# The Contradiction method of proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $A, B, P, Q, R$ and $S$ are integers, where $A=B\cdot P+R$, $A=B\cdot Q+S$ , $0\leq R < |B|$, and $0\leq S<|B|$ prove that $R=S$ and $P=Q$.

Comment: Please change the title to something relevant.

Comment: Each of the two equations represent a straight line. If the 2 lines intersect in more than one point, both would then represent one line, which implies the required result. However, I guess this is not the proof you want.

Comment: Note that, R-S is greater than -|B| and less than |B|, B(Q-P) which is equal to R-S, its absolute value can only be 0, B, 2B, ... for Q-P is Integer.